# How to improve Tesseract results

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, tesseract

I want to detect text in images while using OpenCV and tesseract. My steps are:

1. To detect text I am using the scene text detection algorithm of cv::text. This actually works pretty good also under difficult circumstances
2. Identified text respectively the image area containing the text is extracted from the main image
3. I pass each sub-image to Tesseract

However, tesseract barely finds text and if it finds text, it is wrong. **Example:** (image taken from https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/text/samples/scenetext01.jpg)

[image]

**Green:** Detected text by OpenCV (good).

**Yellow:** The text recognized by tesseract based on the green rectangles (bad)

Extracted text is "DOUBLEI". The 'I' is a result of the black border to the right.

As you can see the other words such as "PROHIBITED" should also be easily detected by tesseract. I tried to increase the size of the extracted sub-images containing text and used thresholding but I can not improve my results.

In various tutorials I see tesseract working under more difficult conditions so it should actually work.

When directly using "tesseract.exe" with the same image no text is detected at all:

[image]

Comment: The only difference i see between the words is that in the word "Prohibted" the letters are smaller and closer to each other. I don't know if this will help but try to rescale the image to be bigger and run again.

Comment: Can you edit your question and attach the extracted text images?

Comment: I will try. What helped was to !significantly! increase the text image sizes, e.g. by 400%. This helped to recognize all text but without the "NOTICE" on top which has a red background.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a little white background. I remember that tesseract had big problems with text that reaches the borders of the image. Add 10px of white to each side and see if it helps.